# What is wrong with this heuristic proof of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem is obvious for continuous functions (as the ball gets small, $f(x)$ approaches a constant). To prove it is true for all measurable functions (up to a set of measure zero), one often passes to the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function and does some non-trivial work. However, why doesn't the following, simpler, argument hold?

By Lusin's Theorem, we know that measurable functions are exactly those which are continuous except on a set of arbitrarily small measure. So why can't we throw a set where $f$ is not continuous and just apply the result for continuous functions? We know that the integral wont be much affected by removing small sets, so nothing seems to be immediately wrong with this. If one would like to be a bit more precise, one could iteratively remove sequences of sets of measure $2^{-i}$ which hold all the discontinuities of $f$ and let the derivative be defined as the limit of that sequence of integrals.

I'm assuming that I'm just missing something obvious because the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem is a bit harder to prove than this. Note that this is not extremely different to the usual approach of proving it for continuous functions then approximating with continuous functions.

Comment: I feel like you're misunderstanding what Lusin's theorem says. Consider the function $f=\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}}$. This is a function $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ which is everywhere discontinuous. However, the restriction $f|_{\Bbb{Q}}:\Bbb{Q}\to\Bbb{R}$ is simply the constant function which maps everything to $1$, so it's continuous relative to the subspace topology on the domain.